# Object object as url params angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I ma some url like this

```
https://app.com/login?redirectPage=http://app2.com/login
```

And in **login component**

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.url.subscribe(() => {
        const redirectPage = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('redirectPage');
        navigatePage = redirectPage;
        this.redirectToPage(navigatePage);
    });
  }

  redirectToPage(page: string): void {
    window.location.replace(page);
  }
}
```

The problem is that in url I got

```
 [object, object]
```

[image]

Comment: At 6k rep you should know that it'd be better if you included a reproduction example.

Comment: This is complete example, i have nothing more just one component

Comment: Have you tried to URI encode the ```url``` to escape the special characters? It may be that angular is trying to parse the URL ```string``` as a ```URLObject```

Comment: OK,, but how to do that, can you kame answer

Comment: Im not really sure this is your problem, I just tried to replicate your issue but failing. Can you please explain how you are using the ```url``` more. In any case, the encoded version should look like this ```redirectPage=http:%2F%2Fapp2.com%2Flogin```

Comment: Also from looking at your screen shot, it looks like the output you would get if you tried to concat a ```string``` with an ```array``` but making a mistake and calling ```toString()``` on the array object

Comment: It is working ok locally, when on server it got this problem

Comment: Can you please explain more on how you are creating and using the ```url```.

Comment: const url = `https//app.com/login?redirectPage=${ApplicationsInfo.LOGIN.redirectPage}`;